# How do I properly configure `drf-spectacular` in my Django projects

Tags: django, drf-spectacular

I simply installed and configured `drf-spectacular` in my Django project, but when I visit the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/schema/`, Django throws this error.

`TypeError at /api/v1/schema/ Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: school>.`

This is my root `urls.py` file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from drf_spectacular.views import SpectacularAPIView, SpectacularRedocView, SpectacularSwaggerView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('schools.urls')),
    path('api/v1/years-terms/', include('years_terms.urls')),
    path('api/v1/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='schema'),
    path('api/v1/schema/redoc/', SpectacularRedocView.as_view(url_name="schema", ), name='redoc'),
    path('api/v1/schema/swagger-ui/', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name="schema"), name='swagger-ui'),
]
```

In my `settings.py` file, I have this

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    "TITLE": "School Veil API Project",
    "DESCRIPTION": "A school management system",
    "VERSION": "1.0.0",
}
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably may want to check your views. That error seems to show because of an unexpected response of a view method or you just gave a serializer some unexpected param. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73812799/field-id-expected-a-number?rq=3) for more info.

Comment: This is not really an answer.